# text on webpage not getting highlighted when selected

Tags: css

Strange behavior which is hard to explain and hard to search appropriately in Google for a solution.

I have developed a [site](http://www.jeeplife.com/jxp/dashboard) with many webpages. Each webpage has the same structure, header with links at top, content area in the middle and footer with legal disclaimer and links at the bottom.

When I try to copy some text on the webpage by selecting it, it gets copied to clipboard and I am able to paste the text elsewhere. But when I actually select the text to copy, the selected text does not get highlighted which is kind of confusing for the end users because they might think it has not been copied when in reality it has been.

Any idea why this is happening? I don't care about other text on the site, but I have a locate a store popup on the site that gives me a list of stores with addresses - users will expect those addresses could be copied to open it up in Google maps or elsewhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming that you've tested this in other browsers to ensure it's not just a quirk in the browser you're using?

Comment: I have tested this on IE and it works fine there, just realized from other answers that I had ::selection{text-shadow: none} in my styles which caused the issue on chrome, firefox and other browsers except IE, not sure why IE ignores that style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `background` to your `::selection` [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aselection). eg:

```
*::-moz-selection { background: red; }
*::selection      { background: red; }
```

Comment: That worked Thanks! I had selection{text-shadow: none} specified in my stylesheet and IE seemed to ignore the style and highlighted text normally, anyways thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should change background of selection text. Its working in your site also

```
::selection {
    background-color: #CC0000;
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/LRY4h/)

Answer (score 1):

You may have the following set:

```
.row-of-icons {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  -o-user-select: none;       /* Opera */
  user-select: none;          
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

Here's the jsfiddle by Chris Coyier:

http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/vGG8F/3/